# Server - Client comunication

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, asp.net, apache

considering websoket connections ex. (javascript client -> php / asp server) or asynchronous ajax requests, I was looking for reverse communication: server-> client, to get a certain response from the server without making the request. Assuming a batch process that runs on server, which communicates the presence of a data ready to the client when the desired data has been processed. Does such architecture exist?

Comment: No it's not possible for the server to notify a client without the client establishing some sort of connection first. What you describe may be solved by "Long polling": https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/long-polling-in-system-design

Comment: Websockets are often used when a server wants to notify a client. Can you please clarify your question? You can use [This documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see the best ways to get a good answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, but you can send small requests "asking" the server if there was any change since the last check. to emulate the behaviour.